# JQuery: How to make DIV within Scroll window focused?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have the following HTML/CSS:

```
#scrollpanel{height:100px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:scroll;width:200px}

<div id="scrollpanel">
    <div class="listing ref_1">...</div>
    <div class="listing ref_2">...</div>
    <div class="listing ref_3">...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

As you can see, the `scrollpanel` is a scrollwindow defined to have a height of 100px and width of 200px.

How can I programmatically scroll the `scrollpanel` scrollbar/window to make a particular DIV focused/viewable, even if that DIV is not not currently viewable?

For example, say I have 10 `DIV`s (ref_1 to ref_10). Only 3 of the ref_ `DIV` can be viewable at a time based on the height of `scrollpanel` window.  Now let's say I want to have the scrollbar auto scrolled to DIV `ref_7`, which is currently not viewable. How do I programmicatly have the scrollwindow scroll to and focus on `ref_7`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the jQuery [ScrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) plugin, it's as simple as:

```
$('#scrollpanel').scrollTo('.ref_7');
```

Comment: That is scrolling the Browser windows and not the scrollpanel window. How do I get it to scroll the scrollpanel window?

Comment: try that now, I missed out the fact that you want the scrollpanel div to scroll

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll an element into view by using [`element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView).

Comment: Is this cross browser supported?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look this plugin.

http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Depending on what you need there may be a simpler solution without using a plug-in if you just want to scroll.